# Register users in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing a script of registration. Here's what I did

Connect.php

```
<?php

$Connessione = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$Database = mysql_select_db('my_database');

if(!$Connessione) {
    echo "Errore di connessione: ".mysql_error;
}
else { 
echo "";
}

?>
```

Register.php

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Registrati o loggati</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Sei nuovo? Registrati! Sei già registrato? Loggati!</h1>
    <form action="full.php" name="registrazione" method="post">
        NickName (Massimo 10 caratteri): <input type="text" name="nickname" maxlenght="10" required/>
        <br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="psw" required/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrati" name="registrati"/>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

full.php

```
<?php
   include('connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['registrati'])) {       
        $Username = $_POST['nickname'];
        $Password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $Escape = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);
        $Query = "INSERT INTO sito (user, password) VALUES($Escape, $Password)";
        $Esecuzione = mysql_query($Query);

        if(!$Esecuzione) {
            echo "Errore: ".mysql_error();
        } else { 
            echo "";
        }
    }
?>
```

When I run it and I click on the button tells me ( and for example in nikcname i put "John" )  Errore: Unknown column 'John' in 'field list'. Why? This code is open to SQL Injection? Thanks

Comment: Strings must be quoted and make sure you always sanitize user inputs so you're safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Don't use mysql and don't use variables in your sql statement .Please use PDO or MSQLi with prepared statement

Comment: @Class prepared statement.tx

Comment: `mysql_error` is a function and need `()` in  connection error

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to quote your values like so:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO `sito` (`user`, `password`) VALUES('$Escape', '$Password')";
```

Also you might want to check out `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: And quote the column names in back ticks, `\`user\``

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would check up on this. Lets convert your ***MySQL*** code to ***MySQLi***. ***MySQL*** is already deprecated.

**Connect.php**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

**full.php**

```
<?php
   include('connect.php');

   if(isset($_POST['registrati'])) {       
        $Username = $_POST['nickname'];
        $Password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $Escape = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);

        /* START OF CHECK IF INPUT IS ALREADY IN DATABASE */

        $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sito WHERE user='$Escape'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){ /* IF USERNAME HASN'T TAKEN YET */

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO sito (user, password) VALUES ('$Escape','$Password')");

        }

        else {
        echo $Escape." is already taken.";
        }

   } /* END OF ISSET REGISTRATI */
 ?>
```